# Ajax / Internet Explorer Encoding problem

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer, character-encoding

I'm trying to use JQuery's autocomplete plug-in but for some reasons Internet Explorer is not compatible with the other browsers:
When there is an accent in the "autocompleted" string it passes it with another encoding.

```
IP - - [20/Apr/2010:15:53:17 +0200] "GET /page.php?var=M\xe9tropole HTTP/1.1" 200 13024 "http://site.com/page.php" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"

IP - - [20/Apr/2010:15:53:31 +0200] "GET /page.php?var=M%C3%A9tropole HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://site.com/page.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.9 Safari/533.2"
```

I would like to know if there is anyway I can still decode those variables to output the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one (IE) is unicode You can try php's unicode functions to handle that.

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

The second one is url encoded.  php also has methods for handling url encoding.

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, can I decode both at the same time?

Comment: Can can run the same string through each function.  Worse case scenario you may have to detect IE8 clients and do something slightly different.